# Client App vs Windows Service vs?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, service, architecture

I am currently looking into some re-architecture for a set of applications for our organization. We currently have a set of 10-15 odd stand-alone applications that communicate to each other and provide an intermediate level between client software and hardware.

Problem with current model is lots of individual apps, which add memory overhead, latency in communication, bloat the system and make it difficult to recover from issues in case of any of these apps crashing.

I am thinking of combining the application into 1-2 logical units that help address some of these issues. The dilemma is on how to do this well:

- Windows Service
- UI Application
- Both?

The goal is to have an always on system that will handle all of the client-hardware comms but also have a rich admin-user configuration UI that will be able to talk to all of the individual components of this system and provide config/etc capabilities. Having a WinForms/WPF application will allow easy admin-user access to the system config and provide real time feedback (camera feed, etc), but will leave this open to admins accidentally closing the window. Having a service doing all of that work is great, but I am not sure on how to provide a rich admin-user UI that interacts and changes this service.

Any ideas or links worth reading?

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be the right place for this question.  Try here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to move this over to there? Never understood what stack exchange was in comparison to stack overflow

Comment: What prevents you from having both a client app and a Windows service, or even a System Tray application?

Comment: You're on the right track, if you need to have an always on service monitoring the hardware comms, you'll want a Windows service. Then you can have a WPF application as the UI which can talk to your service, or talk to a shared local database. You can use RPC to talk to your Windows service from your WPF app, or probably better is to use a SQL database. So your service can be writing data into the database, and your UI can read it out. Another option is to have the UI connect to your service via a TCP socket, and send/receive messages this way.

Comment: I was going to suggest something along the lines of @Mangist. We have an MVC app that communicates with a windows service via WCF. There are lots of options available to you.

Comment: @roryap when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!! :) My biggest reservation is having a Service and WPF app communicate to eachother. Never did anything like that before so not sure if they are any major issues that I will encounter. One of the many things that the WPF app will need to display is an HD video stream from the camera attached to the service - is that straight forward to do with WFC (RPC/sockets)? Will that have substantially bigger performance overhead than doing that directly in the WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just thought I'd update my own question for anyone else that might be having a similar question.

What I went with is a centralized Windows Service that exposes a number of WCF endpoints for a number of its child components. Sitting on top of that is a UI application that communicates to the Windows Service through the WCF endpoints. To make building & debugging easier the Windows Service is configured to run as a Console application when run in debug.

This solution seems to work great so far!